# Building Gtk app for Windows OS - msys2 mingw vs Visual C++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, gtk, mingw, msys2

Are there any advantages for building a Gtk3 app for Windows OS with the MSVC Visual C++ Compiler over msys2 mingw (ucrt64)?
Functionality-wise? Look-wise? Debug-wise?, Deployment-wise?

I'm new in a project that builds Gtk2 apps for Windows with Visual C++. No one really remembers if there was a special reason for using Visual C++.
I was asked to create a build process for the Gtk3 version.

I came up with using Mingw (ucrt64) with msys2 which is one of the ways described on [Gtk Windows page](https://www.gtk.org/docs/installations/windows).

**Packaging and Build**:
I installed the necessary packages with msys2 and I'm able to build the app both with mingw and with Visual C++. With mingw I can use pkgconfig with cmake. With Visual C++ It's not so straight forward - I just give it hard-coded paths.

**Debug**:
When building with mingw I was able to also debug with gdb (also by using VS code). I haven't tried to debug the Visual C++ build yet.

**Deployment**:
After the Mingw build I created some shell script to copy dlls, icons, etc.. to a release dir and I can package this this and deliver it. Is there a better way with Visual C++?

Comment: This is mostly a matter of preference. If the performance of your app matters, you can benchmark different compilers against each other.

Comment: How can I have a preference if I don't know if there's some advantage I'm missing? I'm new to gtk, gtk on Windows, Have little experience with developing on/for Windows and with VC++. Maybe there's someone with more experience who can say if/what are some advantages of using Visual C++.

Comment: Even the people in the project can't say for sure if we're missing something. So let's see if someone can answer. Thanks.

Comment: VS is a nice IDE (debugger gui, and so on), but the compiler is generally less standard-conforming than GCC or Clang. It's also closed-source and not cross-platform.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat You mean to say you have experience developing with both and there's no advantage for building a gtk app with VC++ for Windows?

Comment: Yep, I have some experience, and haven't seen any major advantages/disadvantages other than what I already said.